# How to add Startup.cs in existing project .net5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have an .net5 project and in .csproj file I have this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package to my prject.furturemore I created Dbcontext file like below:

```
using Domian;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;


namespace Mc2.CrudTest.Presentation.Front.Infrastructure
{
        public class DataContext : DbContext
        {
            protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

            public DataContext(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            {
                // connect to sql server with connection string from app settings
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnection"));
            }

            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        }
    
}
```

since there wasn't any startup.cs file in my project ,I created one this way:
[image]

the namespaces of IApplicationBuilder and IWebHostEnvironment coudn't find.
I dont know whether I can use startup.cs file like.net core.3.1 or I shouldn't use startup.cs file in .net5 anymore.

And my program.cs file was formed this way:

```
    using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Mc2.CrudTest.Presentation.Front
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebAssemblyHostBuilder builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped(_ => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();

            builder.Services.AddDbContext(options => options
    
        }
    }
}
```

In addtion my project is BlazorWebAssembly

Comment: You can use Startup.cs in .NET 5, but it doesn't seem like you've created a web project? You need the right dependency references, etc. for this to work.

Comment: You changed the question **completely** and now the answer makes no sense. If you want to ask a new question, post a new question

Comment: People won't bother reading an already answered question. If you want to get answers to your new question, revert this and post a new question

Comment: The *new* question is a compilation error complaining about a missing type parameter. `builder.Services.AddDbContext(` should be `builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(`. This would fail in all .NET Core versions

Comment: After discussing with Amir in comments to my answer it seems the scope of this problem is pretty different from what was originally asked. He needs to spend some time in an example Blazor solution with a separate hosting project from the webassembly SPA project. Things will make a lot more sense after that. I'm gonna suggest the question be closed though since it's pretty far off course at this point. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should add blazerServerApp project which consist of program.cs and startup.cs which you looking for as shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *don't use .NET 5*. It [reached End-of-Life on May 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). That's almost a year ago. EOL means no support at all, for anything, from either Microsoft or NuGet authors. Not even security patches.

It was known from the start this would be a single-year or "Standard-Term" Support version (STS), supported only for 18 months. The Long-Term-Support version is .NET 6, supported until November 2024. LTS versions are supported for 3 years since release.

Second, you don't need Startup.cs in .NET 6 (or .NET 5). The methods found in `Startup.cs` were merged into Program.cs. You can write :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext(options=>options
    .UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlServerConnection")));
```

This is shown in all ASP.NET Core and EF Core tutorials, eg [this Web API tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). In this tutorial, `Program.cs` contains :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TodoApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("TodoList"));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Notice that even `Program.Main` is missing. That's the entire file. This is possible through a few new C# features: top-level statements and implied usings.

If you don't like this style you can use [--use-program-main](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style) to generate a `Program.cs` and `Main` method

Comment: event this way if i add this line of codes in program.cs instead of startup.cs there are some errors such as unknown reference WebApplication.@PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: How did you create that file? Top-level statements work, that's not debatable. All .NET 6 and 7 projects use top-level statements by default. That's what `dotnet new` creates.

Comment: @amirkian you changed the question completely and now the answer makes no sense. Post a new question instead of rewriting the original.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried what you said but it didn't work and added more information and my tryout. It is still the same question .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is .net5 and I don't want to use top-level statements.

Comment: @amirkian you can't *not* use .NET 6. EOL means dead. Not just unsupported but dead.  If you start now, as asking for `Startup.cs` suggests, there's no good reason *at all* to target .NET 5. It's not even `my customers want it`. You can deploy a self-contained application with .NET 6.

Comment: @amirkian as for the question - you don't need Startup.cs in .NET 5 or later. Even if you use `Program.Main`, the configuration and services are available through `builder.Configuration`, `builder.Services`, `builder.Logging` etc

Comment: @amirkian and no, it's not the same question at all. `The type arguments for method 'EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext` has nothing to do with Startup.cs or `Program.Main`, it's a compilation error complaining that the wrong type argumens were used in a generic parameter. You forgot to mention *which* DbContext to register. Even if you have a single DbContext-derived class, the compiler can't know that before compiling the entire solution. Use `.AddDbContext<DataContext>(...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251592/discussion-between-amir-kian-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: A better idea would be to create a new project in whatever runtime you want, .NET 5 or .NET 6, and follow one of the tutorials. Check for example the .NET 5 version of [Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

First off, of course you *should* update to .NET6 or .NET7 if you can[1]. But if that's not practical for whatever reason, then of course you can use `startup.cs`. In fact I prefer to as well, out of habit  (you can use it in .NET6 too; not sure about 7 but I assume so).

You can define `startup.cs` more or less the way you do, but you do need the right `using`'s:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

Less obviously, in your `program.cs` you need

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore;

 ...

 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
 {
      ...
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
      ...
 }
```

Edit - After discussing with Amir in comments below it seems the scope of this problem is pretty different from what was originally asked. I suggest you spend some time in an example Blazor solution with a separate hosting project from the webassembly SPA project. Things will make a lot more sense after that.

[1] Microsoft IMO has done the world a disservice with its post-Framework policy of introducing breaking changes into each ASP.NET version so liberally. It's not always just a matter of retargeting. And that's especially true of Blazor which is still so immature. Certainly if security is a concern for this application you should be doing everything you can to upgrade, but in the real world isn't always that simple.

Comment: Actually what you have said just right for blazorServeApp not for BlazorWebAssebmly.I am looking forward a way to use it in BlazorWebAssebmly.

Comment: @amirkian Wait sorry I assumed this was an asp.net hosting project for a Blazor SPA. You're saying this IS your Blazor SPA?

Comment: .It is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly and I think I should add another blazorServeApp  project to handle this

Comment: @amirkian yes you should. :)  For example you are not going to be able to make database calls from the Blazor SPA. I suggest you create a new project (even if just to have an example) using the "Blazor Webassembly App" template in Visual Studio and when you get to the "Additional Information" page make sure "ASP.NET Core Hosted" is checked. None of this stuff (startup.cs, etc.) belongs in your Blazor SPA project; it should be in the hosting project though.